# why does S3 getObjectMetadata ETAG pads an extra 0

Tags: java, amazon-s3, md5

When i compare the same file on local file system and on S3 i get the same MD5 sum, only difference is S3 has an extra '0' padded to the left ?

Any idea why does that happen, how ever thats not the case for all files, its only for a few.

## this is the local file

jabir: > echo '7f4d91c02fd8709186bf682bc811e16' |wc
       1       1      32

## this is the object on s3

jabir : > echo '07f4d91c02fd8709186bf682bc811e16' |wc 
       1       1      33

This is the code i use to get the md5 (remote)

```
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = s3Client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, key);
String destMd5 = objectMetadata.getETag().toString();
```

(local

```
)

public static String getFileMD5(InputStream is) {
        MessageDigest md = null;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            int numOfBytesRead;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            while ((numOfBytesRead = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                md.update(buffer, 0, numOfBytesRead);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            logStatic.error(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logStatic.error(e);
        }

        byte[] digest = md.digest();

        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, digest);
        String output = bigInt.toString(16);
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is an algorithm intented to produce 16 byte values. In the logic you use to convert the digest to a String you must consider the case where the some of the first values are 0.

For example, imagine the case where the `byte[]` you get from `md.digest()` is `[0, 0, 0, ..., 1]`. In that case, your conversion would yield to the String `"1"`, while the correct MD5 output would be `"00000000000000000000000000000001"`.